# Tensor Flow Model Maker

Tags: python, csv, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-lite

I'm making an mobile app that uses TensorFlow Lite to perform text classification on tweets. I've done this successfully with the TensorFlow sample model but this model is trained on IMDB movie reviews and I want to have a custom model on device that is trained on tweets to increase accuracy. I have training and test sets for this domain and am trying to create a custom model following this tutorial https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/tutorials/model_maker_text_classification

I'm running into a pythion `KeyError` though and cant figure out why. here is a screen shot

[image: TFLite Model Maker]

You can see on the right a sample of my csv, I have a `label` and `Sentence` column, using the TextClassifierDataLoader. I don't understand why this key error is happening, I'm interpreting this as it can't find a column named "Sentence" but cleary it's there.

Any ideas?

Comment: try to print dataframe to see if it prints dataframe properly. Print dataframe labels.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me that is_training is not an available argument in the class, so just take out that line/argument if you want it to compile (what it was supposed to do in the first place, I haven't looked into).

https://github.com/tensorflow/examples/blob/1dc6978e2141e7a5efebcf6971b3afa9cb055679/tensorflow_examples/lite/model_maker/core/data_util/text_dataloader.py#L90

Answer (score 0):

Issue was the column " Sentence" had an empty space at the beginning